# How are meeting appointments connected and how can I use this connection?

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

When I create a meeting and invite some users and they accept, the meeting appointments are in some way internally connected and when I change one, the other changes too. Can I use or extract this connection using exchange managed api? For example when I have a meeting appointment can i get the other appointments belonging to this meeting in my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, cou can. The Appointment.ICalUid property ties meeting instances together accross mailboxes. You need to check the mailboxes of the participants of that meeting and search their default calendar folder for items with the Appointment.ICalUid set to this value.

Answer (score 0):

When you (as the origanizer) modify an appointment, Outlook prompts you to send a meeting update, which the recipient can accept.
What exactly are you trying to do and why?